# How to say “unisex for children” in english language (without sounding weird)

Tags: terminology, grammatical-gender, gender-neutral

I'm trying to find the professional wording that describes "unisex" (male + female) in the children fashion industry. It seems that most fashion shops simply name this "children" or "kids", avoiding the word unisex under all circumstances, probably as there might be a pedophile association with the word "sex".

FYI I'm working in a fashion project that simply needs different words for unisex clothes in both adult and non-adult sections - and "unisex children" sounds way too wrong.

Comment: Have you checked a thesaurus for synonyms of "unisex"? Please mention what other words you've considered and why they don't work so that we're not giving you irrelevant answers.

Comment: Actually unisex works well as would your tag 'gender neutral'.

Comment: The definition of *unisex* makes no distinction as to age. Children's clothing can be unisex in just the same way that adults' clothing can be unisex. Just as you would not say "unisex adults" you also would not say "unisex children." But in each of the sections, adults and children, there could be a unisex area.

Comment: The term I've seen most commonly used for children's clothing is indeed "unisex" -- there is nothing wrong with this, it is an accepted term in the industry as far as I can tell. I suppose you could adopt "unigender" as an alternative if the other term bothers you.

Comment: 'Genderless' works well.

Answer (score 1):

**Gender-neutral.** 
  [https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gender-neutral]   
adjective: gender-neutral
suitable for, applicable to, or common to both male and female genders.
"gender-neutral games and toys"
denoting a word or expression that cannot be taken to refer to one gender only.
"gender-neutral terms like flight attendant, firefighter, and police officer"

Comment: Please cite the source where you got that definition.